# rspec repeating a test over and over

Tags: rspec

how do I repeat a particular test for a different condition in rspec?

right now I do

```
it 'should be able to go through the checkout flow with shipping_address/shipping_fees' do
    @app.account_ids.each_with_index do |account_id, country|
             TEST BODY
        end
end
```

but that does not seem like an elegant way to do it. Is there a better way?

what's the equivalent of repeating the TEST BODY over and over again for each account_id?

Answer (score 0):

You can repeat the `it` call as follows:

```
@app.account_ids.each_with_index do |account_id, country|
   it "should be able to go through the checkout flow with shipping_address/shipping_fees" do
      TEST BODY
   end
end
```

This will allow each instance of `TEST BODY` to fail independently.